# Can't figure out why my DRF login test is not working as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following test case:

```
class CustomUserViewSetTests(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            email="test@email.com", password="testpass123"
        )

    def test_login_with_correct_data(self):
        url = reverse("knox_login")
        resp = self.client.post(
            url,
            data={
                "email": "test@email.com",
                "password": "testpass123",
            },
            format="json",
        )
        respJson = resp.json()
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The test always fails since "resp" has a 400 status code with body {'non_field_errors': ['Unable to log in with provided credentials.']}.

When I check the test database via get_user_model().objects.all(), I can see that the user exists.

Also, when I call the url via Postman, I get status code 200 with token and user details returned in body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `objects.create()`. This is fine as long as you want to create a `Car`, `Item` or `Thing` without passwords. For the `User` model though, since it is dealing with password hashing, you want to use its special [`.create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method.

Your create method writes `'testpass123'` as raw string to the database. But your login logic first hashes that string, and then tries to login. Then the login fails because it is trying to match raw stored password from the database to the hash of the login form password.

```py
class CustomUserViewSetTests(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Create a user with a hashed password
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email="test@email.com", password="testpass123"
        )
```

When you are using the `.create_user()` method it takes the raw password string, hashes it and then stores the hash to the database. When you then log in, the same logic is applied. The user inserts the raw password, its getting hashed and then the hash is compared to the stored hash from the database.

My answer only applies if the user model that you're using inherits from django's [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) (django.contrib.auth)

Comment: thanks, I actually used .create_user() in my CustomUser tests... now it works.